# Do Firebase FIrestore Listeners unsubscribe when app is closed?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app, that listens to the firestore realtime snapshots. I wanted to ask whether closing the app would unsubscribe all listeners?

If not then how to unsubscribe all firestore listeners when app is closed in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the realtime database, you can use the `componentDidUnMount` cycle hook.

UPDATE: As puf noticed, you are using a firestore, so I will include BOTH ways, make sure you pick the right one for you. Notice with firestore, `onSnapshot` returns an unsubscribe function, you can use it on the cyclehook.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
        this.realtimeDB = firebase.database().ref().child('yourNode') /* ... etc...*/
        this.firestoreDB = null
        this.state = { something: [] }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
       const colRef = firebase.firestore().collection("your_collection").doc(YOURDOCID)
        this.firestoreDB = colRef.onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var something = [];
             querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
               something.push(doc.data());
             });
            that.setState({ something })
        });
    }
    

   componentWillUnMount() {
       this.realTimeDB.off()
    
       this.firestoreDB()
   }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But OP is using Firestore, not Realtime Database.

Comment: ops ^^ god catch!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not automatically close all listeners when the app closes. But your operating system typically closes all such connections when it closes an app.

I'd still recommend unsubscribing explicitly though, as @andresmijares shows in their answer.